# Cannot use GTalk in Pidgin after enabling 2 step verification

Tags: google-talk

I was unable to use GTalk from my Pidgin IM after enabling two step authentication for Google.
I get an error that the account is disabled. How can I get around that?

Answer (score 18):

After enabling Google's 2-step authentication, you have to create app specific passwords for some apps. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords and create a password for Pidgin. Then use the password that Google will generate in Pidgin.

Answer (score 8):

A) First Signin to gmail account.

B) Now visit [IssuedAuthSubTokens](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) Link. Enter the password again if it ask.

C) In step 1, Type 'GTalk' & click 'Generate Password'

D) Now it shows a password with characters. Copy that password in notepad and save it safely. ( Important )

E) Click 'Done'.

Now access Gtalk. Enter username and then paste the password you copied in password field. Finally click 'signin'. Now gtalk login successfully!

Comment: (D) is wrong, you do not have to store this password as it is a one-time password. Google even mentions "No need to memorize this password. You should need to enter it only once. "

Comment: no, its not for one-time,
i have created 1 password and still using it and now more then 3 month

Comment: But you shouldn't. You should have an app-passwd for **each** different gtalk client. That is the _very reason_ for this whole app-specific password solution.

Comment: **2016 UPDATE**  *1.* Sign-in to your 2-factor-authentication enabled google account.  *2.* Go to "Sign In & Security" section. *3.* Look for *Singning into Google* >> *Password & sign-in method* >> *App Passwords*.  Now, select App - (custom) can be selected and name your app whatever you want - "Pidgin" for example and select the device for which you want the password.  Now, **GENERATE** a password.  Finally, COPY & PASTE that password in your app for which you want to login with Google Account - except now you'll enter this password here instead of your original app password.  Good Luck.

Comment: Akash; that worked for me, should have added that as an answer. Thanks!